# How to keep accented character, letters numbers and symbols

Tags: c#, regex

How to keep letters, numbers, symbols and accented characters c#. I would like to get rid of emojis and the "最高" characters. This works but it is ignoring new lines.

```
string Message = @"The cédille (cedilla) Ç ...The Accent aigu (acute accent) é ...
        The Accent circonflexe (circumflex) â, ê, î, ô, û ...
        The accent grave (grave accent) à, è, ù ...
        The accent tréma (dieresis/umlaut) ë, ï, ü" 最高 ;

var msg = Regex.Match(Message, @"[a-zA-zÀ-ÿ0-9/ [.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()?<>]+");

Console.WriteLine(msg);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: by using different `Encoding` probably

Comment: The requirements are not quite clear. What type of letters do you need to match? I suspect you want to match all ASCII chars and all Latin - `[\x00-\x7F\p{IsLatin-1Supplement}\p{IsLatinExtended-A}\p{IsLatinExtended-B}\p{IsLatinExtendedAdditional}]+`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me you only want to keep the ASCII characters, and not all other character set (like UTF-8/16) characters.

This would do:

```
string msg = new string(Message.Where(c => ((int)c) < 256).ToArray());
```

Comment: Some unicode-characters (Emojis) are made of multiple characters and one of those characters could match  `(int)c) < 256` e.g. `string msg = new string("*️⃣#️⃣*️⃣".Where(c => ((int)c) < 256).ToArray());`

Comment: @fubo nice catch. I don't know how to fix that besides walking down the characters and check them against the UTF-8 documentation. Maybe something like this could help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/23940623/993547

Comment: all keycap characters are matching that condition - no idea how to fix this, just wanted to point that out http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html#keycap

Answer (score 1):

use `Matches` method

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(Message, @"[a-zA-zÀ-ÿ0-9/ [.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()?<>]+");
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

that will return you `MatchCollection` which you can easily transform into string with line breaks.

```
string message = "";
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    message += match.Value + Environment.NewLine;
}

Console.WriteLine(message);
```