# How to convert utf8 byte array to a string of given length

Tags: c#, string, utf-8, byte

Let's say I have an array of bytes:

```
var myArr = new byte[] { 0x61, 0x62, 0xc4, 0x85, 0xc4, 0x87 };
```

So it has 6 elements while it corresponds to utf8 `abąć` which has 4 letters. Typically you do

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetString(myArr);
```

to convert it to a string. But lets assume that `myArr` is actually bigger (there are more bytes at the end) but I do know (a priori to conversion) that I only want the first 4 letters. How can efficiently convert this array to the string? Also it would be preferable to have the index of the last byte in `myArr` array (corresponding to the end of the converted string).

Example:

```
// 3 more bytes at the end of formerly defined myArr
var myArr = new byte[] { 0x61, 0x62, 0xc4, 0x85, 0xc4, 0x87, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03 };
var str = MyConvert(myArr, 4); // read 4 utf8 letters
// str is "abąć"
// possibly I want to know that MyConvert stoped at the index 6 in myArr
```

The resulting `string str` object should have `str.Length == 4`.

Comment: _"How can efficiently convert this array to the string?"_ - by calling `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(myArr)`, regarding code length it doesn't get any more efficient than that. What's your question? What do you mean by the last sentence?

Comment: @CodeCaster You're missing the point. The `GetString()` method won't stop where it is supposed to, it will try to parse **entire** array. And I do want it to stop after `X` letters. Imagine that there are 3 more bytes at the end of `myArr`. I want it to stop after sixth byte. I know that the string has 4 letters beforehand. That's all.

Comment: I hope my edit clarified that then. So that's a hard problem, because you only know in how many characters a byte array will result while you're decoding it. You can encounter a multibyte character, a surrogate pair, and so on. (How) do you want to handle zero-length characters?

Comment: So you don't know how many bytes to decode, just the length of the resulting string? Then I think you have to decode the byte-array yourself...

Comment: How about take the first 16 bytes, convert that and then take the first 4 chars form that?

Comment: @DavidG The conversion may fail, the rest of the byte array does not have to be utf8. I'm working on a efficient serialization. There might be an arbitrary sequence of bytes after the utf8 string.

Comment: @Michael Yeah, manual decoding is always an option. I thought there might be some nicer solution.

Comment: Does it fail completely or just up to the point where it gets stuck?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23940623/how-to-decode-an-utf8-encoded-string-split-in-two-buffers-right-in-between-a-4-b

Comment: @DavidG I didn't try it to be honest. I'm not sure where it fails. :D Anyway you can't know a priori where it fails. The sequence is random afterwards, it might accidentaly contain some utf8 chars. But I see the point, I can get a substring of 4 chars. And from that I can deduce the "cut" index. Still in worse case scenario I will parse entire byte array.

Comment: To check: do you want up to 4 `char` values (UTF-16 code units) or up to 4 Unicode code points? Suppose the byte array is entirely made up of surrogate pairs - do you want 8 chars or 4 in that case?

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm not sure what you are refering to. The initial array (or rather the begining) is utf8 encoded. And the example has 4 unicode characters.

Comment: @freakish yes, but Unicode characters beyond code point 0xFFFF require two C# `char`s (being UTF-16) to be represented.

Comment: @freakish: Sure, but imagine this situation: it's all text, hundreds of characters. Each of those characters is outside the Basic Multilingual Plane, so will be represented as two `char` values in .NET. What would you expect to be returned? A string with a length of 4, representing 2 Unicode characters, or a string with a length of 8, representing 4 Unicode characters?

Comment: @JonSkeet Oh, got ya. I'm interested in a string of length 4.

Comment: @freakish: Good - that's what my answer gives you. It's probably worth updating the question to clarify that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like [`Decoder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.text.decoder?view=netframework-4.7) has your back here, in particular with the somewhat huge [`Convert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.text.decoder.convert?view=netframework-4.7#System_Text_Decoder_Convert_System_Byte___System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Char___System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Boolean_System_Int32__System_Int32__System_Boolean__) method. I think you'd want:

```
var decoder = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
var chars = new char[4];
decoder.Convert(bytes, 0, bytes.Length, chars, 0, chars.Length,
    true, out int bytesUsed, out int charsUsed, out bool completed);
```

Complete sample using the data in your question:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var bytes = new byte[] { 0x61, 0x62, 0xc4, 0x85, 0xc4, 0x87, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03 };
        var decoder = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
        var chars = new char[4];
        decoder.Convert(bytes, 0, bytes.Length, chars, 0, chars.Length,
            true, out int bytesUsed, out int charsUsed, out bool completed);
        Console.WriteLine($"Completed: {completed}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Bytes used: {bytesUsed}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Chars used: {charsUsed}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Text: {new string(chars, 0, charsUsed)}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can a `char[4]` contain all possibilities for four code points representable by UTF-8? I mean, code points over 0xFFFF will use two `char`s, don't know what the OP wants exactly, nor whether they want to support those.

Comment: @CodeCaster:Ah, I'd assumed the OP wanted four UTF-16 code units. Good point - will ask for clarification.

Comment: That works like a charm! And I additionally learned that `char` is actually 2 bytes in C#. Great, thanks.